# Linux dump, which folders/files are excluded from first backup?

Tags: linux, backup, dump

When using dump, level 0, to save the whole concerned partition :

```
$ dump -0f /path/to/target/drive /
```

I'm said some folders are excluded (I guess, at least, *tmp* folder).
I have not found more detail about it.
What is the default excluded folder list please ?

Comment: Have you read  `man dump` ? the `-e option`. I suggest you take a look at some Mint documentation to get a better understanding of what you want to do. eg. [Minit Community](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1577) Think also about your partition setup, do you have a separate partition for /home ? Try to work out a strategy. I get the feeling `dump` isn't the right command for what you want, there were suggestions provided on your other recent  questions. There are also topics in the [Mint Forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=131877) that might help.

Comment: Is `/tmp` mounted on a separate filesystem?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick : /tmp is not.

Comment: @XTian : have you a good link for **man dump** please ?

Comment: Try typing [man dump](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=man%20dump) into Google

Comment: Oh thanks, i did not know Google. It s fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is excluded. It's a level 0 dump, it dumps everything on that **file system**.

A level 1 dump would dump everything that was changed since the last level 0 dump.

A level 2 dump would change everything changed up to the last level 1 dump (if there was a level 1 dump, otherwise back to the level 0 dump).

Hence you could do [incremental backups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_backup) by doing a level 0, then 1, then 2 etc, until you do your next level 0 and start over again.  If you need to restore, you'd have to restore your level 0, then 1 on top of that, then 2 and so on.

You could do [differential backups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_backup) by first doing a level 0, then doing level 1 backups, until your next level 0.  This has the benefit of if you have to restore a file, or the entire file system, there's only 2 places to look, in either the latest level 1 or the level 0.  You could save each of the intervening level 1 backups to be able to undelete a file that was newer than in the level 0 but older than the most recent level 1.

Note: If /tmp is on a different file system, then it is not dumped.  Dump works on a file system bases.  Hence if you have 3 file systems mounted, you will need to dump them 3 times.  Furthermore, dump dumps the entire file system, you can't dump a directory.  Use tar for that!

Comment: ok thanks. There is no "intelligence", I mean, the whole FS is put in the dump "partition".

Comment: Correct.  It walks through the entire file system inode by inode and dumps it all.  It's like one of the original dump programs written for Unix ages ago.  I used it to do tape dumps back when I was at the University.

Comment: tapes... if ever you have time to share photo on a blog, makes me curious. Thank you @MichaelGrant